# What SQL datatype should be used to populate a Solr location (spatial) field when using a DataImportHandler?

Tags: solr, geospatial, dataimporthandler

I have a Solr schema which contains a `location` field (using the default `solr.LatLonType` ):

```
<field name="latlng" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

And I am trying to populate it using a DataImportHandler.  Currently I `SELECT` the value as nvarchar in the format of `17.74628,-64.70725`; however it is not populating the Solr field (it remains empty).

What type and format should this column be in to update the `location` field in Solr?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

solr.LatLonType is a multi-dimensional type; You can define the field type as:

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
```

Using your field name of "latlng" the schema for the coordinate fields will look like this (notice the "subFieldSuffix" used for the 2 dimensional field type solr.LatLonType):

```
<field name="latlng" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="latlng_0_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="latlng_1_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

"latlng_0_coordinate" should be the latitude and "latlng_1_coordinate" should be the longitude. Your select statement should load "latlng_0_coordinate" and "latlng_1_coordinate" as doubles.

Comment: Thanks!  I found this same solution and have implemented it successfully.

Answer (score 3):

the previous answer works since you're manually creating the fields that Solr uses to store the lat and long individually, however there's a dynamic field for that purpose.

`<!-- Type used to index the lat and lon components for the "location" FieldType -->
   <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false" />`

If you check field type location, you might find it uses the suffix _coordinate for their values:

`<!-- A specialized field for geospatial search. If indexed, this fieldType must not be multivalued. -->`

`<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>`

that works for me in Solr 4 beta, and I believe is present since Solr 3.6 or even older. Anyway, just another solution!

Hope this helps.